# Selenium [ Javascript ] - Unable to click shadow dom element

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am unable to click elements of shadow dom elements [ Refer image attached ].

```
var propelement = await wdriver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="rptLoadingFrame"]'));
var pdf_url = await propelement.getAttribute('src')
wdriver.get(pdf_url);
//var download1  = await wdriver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="download"]'));
//download1.click();
//var element = "document.querySelector('#viewer').shadowRoot.querySelector('#toolbar').shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloads').shadowRoot.querySelector('#download').shadowRoot.querySelector('#icon').click()";

await wdriver.executeScript("document.querySelector('#viewer').shadowRoot.querySelector('#toolbar').shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloads').shadowRoot.querySelector('#download').shadowRoot.querySelector('#icon').click()");
```

Getting below error message

"JavascriptError: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'shadowRoot')"

Kindly help.

1. PDF viewer is embedded within iframe and no DOM visible accept  element inside Embed element with #Shadow Root (user-agent)

[image]

2. When I access SRC mentioned in iframe got below DOM i.e. PDF viewer. I want to click "Download" button to download the PDF.

[image]